# Сохранение два раза в базу данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Я изучаю sqlite3, как сделать так, чтобы при прописке playe имя ещё раз не создавалось в таблице?

вот мой не рабочий код:

```
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect("Stats.db")
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player(
    name TEXT,
    cash INT,
    level INT
)""")
connect.commit()

playe = input("Ваш никнэйм: ")
balance = 10
leve = 0

def start():
    print(f"\nНачать(/p)\nНастройки(/n)\nНовости(/w)")

cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM player WHERE name = {playe}")
if cursor.fetchone() is None:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO player VALUES(?,?,?);", (playe, balance, leve))
    connect.commit()
    start()
else:
    start()
```

Comment: Зачем проверка с `cursor.fetchone() is None`, если выше нет `SELECT`?

Comment: @gil9red исправил. Однако он пишет, что не найдена колонна(после ввода input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действия:

- Исправил ошибку, которая приводит к тому, что всегда при запуске добавляется игрок. Причина в проверке `cursor.fetchone() is None` без предварительного вызова `SELECT`
- Добавил уникальность поля `name` (нужно будет удалить таблицу/базу данных, либо через [запрос руками добавить уникальность](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15497985/5909792))

Пример:

```
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect("Stats.db")
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player(
    name TEXT UNIQUE,
    cash INT,
    level INT
)
""")
connect.commit()

playe = input("Ваш никнэйм: ")
balance = 10
leve = 0

def start():
    print(f"\nНачать(/p)\nНастройки(/n)\nНовости(/w)")

cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM player WHERE name = ?", [playe])

# Если игрока нет в базе
if not cursor.fetchone():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO player VALUES(?,?,?);", (playe, balance, leve))
    connect.commit()

start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы не было дубликатов в таблице нужно:

- на уровне БД создать уникальный констрейнт
- в бизнес логики использовать апсерт с последующим апдейтом или исключением

Comment: Можно подробнее? с кодом

Comment: `апсерт` это insert с режимом обновления при дублировании?

Comment: Да, но здесь посыл был абстрактей - если нужно обновлять, то здесь именно то что вы написали, если нужно предотвратить вставку, то здесь после проверки исключение\сообщение.